# MySQL dump works fine importing from command line, but flyway blows up

Tags: mysql, flyway

I have a mysqldump that I've used to successfully import into a db using the command line:

```
mysql -u root dbname < my.sql
```

However if I try to run it as a flyway migration I get the following:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

I was under the impression that if it works fine loading into mysql directly it should work just as well as a flyway migration.

Any thoughts?

Example lines:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `agent`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `agent` (
```

There are a lot of that character set line, so I'm assuming it's failing on the first.

Answer: There was a comment on one of the tables that had a " in it, unmatched. Mysql imported it just fine and ignored it but flyway didn't like it and complained.

Comment: can you paste couple more statements in the dump before and after `SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client` ?

Comment: I think it does not like the semi-colons at the end of the commented area. Perhaps move them before the */